# Wie sagt man " To attend a CPR training" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb-choice

> Ehe ich  Krankenpfleger beendet habe, ging ich zu einer Wiederbelebung.

Before i finished Nursing, I attended a CPR training.

Kann man  an einem `CPR-Training teilnehmen` schreiben oder?

Comment: *"Zum Abschluss meiner Ausbildung als Krankenpfleger besuchte ich ..."*

Comment: Bei Krankenschwestern heißt der Begriff Reanimationsfortbildung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im medizinischen Fachgebrauch sind neben der [bereits erwähnten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/10213/23) Herz-Lungen-Wiederbelebung noch folgende Begriffe gebräuchlich:

- kardiopulmonale Reanimation
- Reanimation
- lebensrettende Maßnahmen/Sofortmaßnahmen
- Erste Hilfe *(Oberbegriff, der aber auch die Reanimation beinhaltet)*

Die gebräuchlichste Bezeichnung eines Fachkurses zum Erlernen von Reanimationsmaßnahmen ist

**Reanimationskurs**

Es gibt aber nach Empfehlung des [deutschen Rates für Wiederbelebung](http://www.grc-org.de/kursangebot) eine Reihe von speziellen Kursen, deren Bezeichnungen aus den europäischen Richtlinien stammen, und die in der Regel nicht übersetzt werden:

- Basic Life Support (BLS), Advanced Life Support (ALS), European Pediatric Life Support (EPLS), Immediate Life Support (ILS), Newborn Life Support (NLS)

Answer (score 2):

CPR als Abkürzung ist im deutschen nur teilweise verbreitet, wird aber verstanden. Der deutsche Begriff ist [Herz-Lungen-Wiederbelebung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herz-Lungen-Wiederbelebung) oder Herz-Lungen-Massage.

Der Satz müsste also lauten:

> Ehe ich meine Ausbildung als Krankenpfleger beendet hatte, ging ich zu einem CPR-Training.

oder

> Ehe ich meine Ausbildung als Krankenpfleger beendet hatte, ging ich zu einem Kurs für Herz-Lungen-Wiederbelebung.

"... ging ich zu einer Wiederbelebung" kannst du nicht verwenden. Das tönt entweder sehr esoterisch (jemand wird von den Toten auferstehen) oder man würde darunter verstehen, dass du selbst wiederbelebt werden musstest. Dann gehst du da aber nicht selber hin.

Comment: Echt? Aber man kann `Ich ging zur Wurzelkanalbehandlung` sagen. Wieso nicht den, den ich gebildet habe?

Comment: nebenbei: ich hätte *CPR* nicht einordnen können... @DerPoly du kannst auf jeden Fall `zum CPR-Training gehen`, nur die Wiederbelebung war danebengegriffen :(

Comment: Man kann "Ich ging zur Wurzelbehandlung" sagen. Das heisst, dass man an der Zahnwurzel behandelt wurde. Genauso heisst "Ich ging zur Wiederbelebung", dass man untot war und wiederbelebt wurde.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: Die (Wurzelkanal)behandlung ist etwas, das (durch jemand anderen) an dir durchgeführt wird. Genauso wird auch eine Wiederbelebung durch jemand anderen an dir durchgeführt. In English: You're going to a course for resurrection, you'll hardly go yourself to your resurrection.

Answer (score 0):

Deine Frage: Was das Verb betrifft, so ist *an einem Kurs teilnehmen* oder *an einem Fortbildungskurs teilnehmen* normales Deutsch.

Zum Namen des Kurses:
Ich habe *CPR-Training* nicht verstanden. Aber du schreibst wahrscheinlich an Leute im Bereich Krankenpflege. Für mich als Medizinlaie wäre "Training über Wiederbelebungsmaßnahmen" am einfachsten zu verstehen.

Comment: "Trainung über Wiederbelebungsmaßnahmen"? Wenn Training (habs direkt mal gefixed), aber das ist so "sportlich". Also doch lieber "Fortbildung", was du eingangs vorgeschlagen hast.

Comment: Ja, Fortbildung in Wiederbelebungsmaßnahmen ist gut.